# Where can I download the exe files used in poppler (python)?

Tags: python, exe, poppler

I installed the latest poppler via

```
conda create --name newenv poppler
```

The installed folder have exe files in them like pdftotext.exe, pdfattach.exe

Is there somewhere where I can down the exe files of Poppler directly without using conda install?

I can't use conda install on my office laptop.

Thank you

Comment: You can download the Conda packages from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poppler/files?page=3

Comment: Off-site resource requests are categorically off-topic here. See #4 in the list of exceptions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows it is confusing which version to use. Current poppler stable is poppler-21.09

```
Release 21.09.0:
        core:
         * Splash: Massive speed improvement on files that use lots of save/restore (q/Q) operators
         * Correct decoding of signature properties Reason & Location when they are Unicode
         * Fix issues with malformed files
         * MSVC build fixes
```

Conda-Forge is usually up to date

So sort into this order and look for newest (not always the latest stable) see the high number of downloads for 6 month old version, but often users dont update to newest. Currently conda-forge is at `21.08..._1` perhaps wait and check in a day or two.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poppler/files?sort=basename&sort_order=desc&page=1

Also note they are (for windows unusually) filename.tar.bz2 and windows native TAR version seems reluctant to handle them so requires 7-Zip or similar extractor !!

I suggest you unpack the set to a New folder then drill down to

`New folder\poppler-21.08.0-h24fffdf_1.tar\Library\bin`

and there find the latest set

```
Directory of C:\Users\name\Downloads\New folder\poppler-21.08.0-h24fffdf_1.tar\Library\bin

2021-09-04  02:02    <DIR>          .
2021-09-04  02:02    <DIR>          ..
2021-08-23  15:58            20,480 pdfattach.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            25,088 pdfdetach.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            22,528 pdffonts.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            48,640 pdfimages.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            57,344 pdfinfo.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            20,992 pdfseparate.exe
2021-08-23  15:58           119,808 pdftocairo.exe
2021-08-23  15:58           103,424 pdftohtml.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            45,568 pdftoppm.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            43,520 pdftops.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            56,832 pdftotext.exe
2021-08-23  15:58            34,816 pdfunite.exe
2021-08-23  15:58           154,112 poppler-cpp.dll
2021-08-23  15:58           340,480 poppler-glib.dll
2021-08-23  15:57         5,299,712 poppler.dll
              15 File(s)      6,393,344 bytes
```

The docs in MAN format are nested in Folder

`New folder\poppler-21.08.0-h24fffdf_1.tar\Library\share\man\man1`

but in that format are as useful as chocolate kettles to a windows user and the wiki is not much better. https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/poppler/

There is a slightly slower spin-off track that repackages Conda-Forge versions into **ZIP** so is more useful to windows natives but currently at `21.08.0` is two steps behind the nix versions.

https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows